# Broken Category/Tag Previous Entries/Next page links in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, broken-links

When I view the list of posts in one category the links for Previous Entries/Next Page are broken:
Instead of: /blog/category/category-name/page/2/

I get: /blog/page/2/?category_name=category-name
And that takes me to page/2/ of all my blog posts so page 2 of category-name is not accessible.

I changed some code in my template but I couldn't get it working. Can anyone help? Have you got any snippets of how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It's long to explain in detail. See this Wordpress Codex guide:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

And this function reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: I've seen those pages and I couldn't get it working. See the URL structure I posted? Maybe it's some kind of rewriting issue?